# C# Mirror API sample - IAuthenticator is deprecated, what to replace it with?

Tags: c#, google-glass

Downloaded the Mirror API quickstart solution, which uses (among other things) the IAuthenticator interface.  That interface was deprecated in version 1.6 of the API and will be removed in 1.7.0-beta.  The compiler hint says to consider using UserCredential or ServiceAccountCredential from the Google.Apis.Auth package instead.

I'm relatively new to the Google APIs, and it's not clear to me the scope of things that need to be changed in the Mirror API quickstart solution so that it no longer uses IAuthenticator, and uses one of the two alternatives instead.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Mark - did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UserCredential credential = ....;
MirrorService service = new MirrorService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential );
```